# Validating email before sending it from validated PHP form

Tags: php, validation, email

I'm using this code from W3 (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp) to make server side validation for given example form.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
     if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
     $website = "";
   } else {
     $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
     // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
     if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
       $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
     $comment = "";
   } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
     $genderErr = "Gender is required";
   } else {
     $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}


?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
   <br><br>
   Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="male">Male
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php



echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Although server side validation works fine,I can't put mail() function to work ONLY WHEN both $name (treated as subject) and $comment (treated as message) fields are filled. 
I've tried many combinations but email is always submitted even when fields are empty.

So my question is: how to make this validated form send email only when $name and $comment fields are filled and validated?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: where exactly are you calling mail function?

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: @JohnConde Really,can you elaborate? I thought they're the most reliable. Keep in mind that I'm a beginner.

Comment: @Johnny click on the link in my comment ;)

Comment: @JohnConde That's a nice,new pathway,thanks!

Comment: @Johnny because high percantage of the information in w3schools are inaccurate, contain errors or outdated. if it comes up first in a google search, it does not mean they are the most reliable source for the searched subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are creating $nameErr when the name is invalid and $comment is an empty string when the comment is valid you can use the following conditional:

```
if (!$nameErr && $comment) {
}
```

Empty strings are considered FALSE:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: Thank You. I was using if statement but with "$name" variable, not "$nameErr". 

As far as I understand, when form is corectly validated, "$nameErr" is obviously empty (there was no mistake) so in our if condition we must use "!" to make it "true" hence whole && condition evaluates to "true".

However if I use "$name" variable in && condition instead of "nameErr",it would evaluate to "true" even when "$name" field is empty because script adds: "test_input($_POST["name"]);" to "$name" variable making it true,right?

Comment: yes, however unless there is any reason why you want the email to send when there are errors in the email or gender etc, then setting up an error flag might be more useful, just make a var that gets set to FALSE if any of the tests find an error and only run your email script if the var is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use flags.

```
<?php

  ....

   // let's say there are some flags for validation
   if($flag1 && $flag2 && .. $flagN){
     // perform email sending here
   }
?>
```

Or you can use the default error message variables; check if they are empty

```
<?php
       if(!empty($nameErr) && !empty($comment)){
         // perform email sending
       }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
What are flags in PHP?I've never encountered them.

Comment: The flags are simply boolean vars, that you can set to false if you find a validation error

Answer (score 0):

Do the validation after you validated $name and $comment:

```
 if($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "") { // If they are empty, no errors where found
 // Do your email validation here
 }
```

Comment: Yes,thats what I was thinking,thanks :) 
I used "$name" variable instead of "$nameErr". 
"$name" variable in this script will always evaluate to true, because even when empty, script will convert "" to '&quot; due to htmlspecialchars() function ,right?

Comment: No, htmlspecialchars converts only html symbols. If you have a letter, number, space or etc. it will stay that way. Also if you have only a space in your text input trim will clean it.

Check what htmlspecialchars does http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: So,why "$name" variable will evaluate to true even when field is empty? That's my only concern.

Comment: Because its a string not a boolean. If you do a if($name), you check if there is a variable $name, not if the variable is empty. Its the same as if(isset($name)), which is not the same as if(empty($name))

Comment: So only"if(empty($name))" will give me "false" with empty field,right?
"nameErr" will evaluate to false even when it's a string because it's haven't been used in correctly validated form?

Comment: Ok, i will try to explain it from the start.

So if you have a string $variable = "", if you do 
if($variable), it will return false, but if the value is " ", it will return true. When using if(empty($variable)), it will return false for the both cases. That is my you should not check only with if($variable). I hope I explained it correctly, this time.